# How to restrict users to rename the llst view of Account object

Tags: list-view

Can someone please let me know how to restrict users to rename the llst view of Account object.

I have a list view on Account object with name "My Org Accounts".I would like to restrict users to rename this list view name.

I think, apex trigger will not be supported on ListView object.

Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: If users have `Manage Public List View` permission then they can edit the list views and rename them. Users can always rename the list view that they have created

Comment: If a list view is created by User A, can it be renamed by User B if UserB has "Manage Public List View" ?